# Multidimensional array or hashes replaces from *INI file to main file

Tags: perl

My Input `*INI` file contains:

```latex
\amacro{(.*?)}{(.*?)}   \amacro{$2}{$1}
\bmacro{(.*?)}{(.*?)}{(.*?)}{(.*?)} \bmacro{$4}{$3}{$2}{$1}
\cmacro{(.*?)}{(.*?)}{(.*?)}{(.*?)}{(.*?)}{(.*?)}{(.*?)}{(.*?)} \cmacro{$4}{$3}{$2}{$1}{$5}{$6}{$7}{$8}
```

My Input Main `*TEX` file contains:

```latex
\section{Introduction}

$\text{AuAl}_{2}$, $\text{AuGa}_{2}$, and $\text{AuIn}_{2}$ with the   
fluorite($\text{CaF}_{2}$)-type cubic structure `\amacro{item1}{item2}`, as   
shown in Fig.~\ref{CaF2_structure}, were once studied from an `\bmacro{item1}  
{item2}{item3}{item4}` interest of colors because $\text{AuAl}_{2}$ has a   
striking reddish-purple color, whereas $\text{AuGa}_{2}$ and   
$\text{AuIn}_{2}$ are neutral and bluish, respectively. The reddish-purple   
color of $\text{AuAl}_{2}$ results from a reflectance minimum in the green   
spectra range (around 2.2~eV), revealing that $\text{AuAl}_{2}$ absorbs green    
and reflect purple~\cite{Vishnubhatla1967}. From the results of   `\cmacro{item1}{item2}{item3}{item4}{item5}{item6}{item7}{item8}` 
synchrotron-radiation-excited angle-resolved   
photoemission experiment, the energy band structure was clarified   
experimentally, which was compared with the results of the band calculation   
based on the augmented plane wave (APW) method with the muffin-tin potential   
approximation.
```

My Expected output on `*TEX` should be:

```latex
$\text{AuAl}_{2}$, $\text{AuGa}_{2}$, and $\text{AuIn}_{2}$ with the   
fluorite($\text{CaF}_{2}$)-type cubic structure `\amacro{item2}{item1}`, as   
shown in Fig.~\ref{CaF2_structure}, were once studied from an `\bmacro{item4}{item3}{item2}{item1}`
interest of colors because $\text{AuAl}_{2}$ has a   
striking reddish-purple color, whereas $\text{AuGa}_{2}$ and   
$\text{AuIn}_{2}$ are neutral and bluish, respectively. The reddish-purple   
color of $\text{AuAl}_{2}$ results from a reflectance minimum in the green   
spectra range (around 2.2~eV), revealing that $\text{AuAl}_{2}$ absorbs green    
and reflect purple~\cite{Vishnubhatla1967}. From the results of `\cmacro{item4}{item3}{item2}{item1}{item5}{item6}{item7}{item8}` 
synchrotron-radiation-excited angle-resolved   
photoemission experiment, the energy band structure was clarified   
experimentally, which was compared with the results of the band calculation   
based on the augmented plane wave (APW) method with the muffin-tin potential   
approximation.
```

I need to check the `*INI` file and replace the regex as per the `*INI` file into the main `*TEX` file. Note: `item` should be a any string like `(.*?)`.
Using the `*INI` file for users purpose ( a lot of lists to be changed sample here)

---

My Code (Not Completed):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Cwd;

my ($texfile, $inifile) = qw(test.tex tags.ini);

readFileinString($inifile, \ my $inicnt);

sub readFileinString
{
    my ($filename, $content) = @_;
    open my $fh, '<', $filename or die "$filename: $!";
    $$content = do { local $/; <$fh> };
}

my @iniCnts = split/\n/, $inicnt; #print join "\n", @iniCnts;
my (@fpush,%stores) = "";
foreach my $iniline(@iniCnts)
{
    my($find, $repl) = split /\t/, $iniline; my $fspush; my $j = 1;
    while($repl=~m/(\{[^{}]*\})/g){  $stores{$j} = $1;  $j++;  } #$fspush .= $1; }
    print sort values \%stores;
    #$fspush,"\n";
    system 'pause';
}
```

In my code I got two values from `*INI` separated by tab delimit and one is `finding` and `replacing` values. Hereafter I want to replace in main `*TEX` file based on the user input in `*INI` file. How can I use the regex in replacing the finding values `#1` into corresponding values. (Refer `*INI` file).

Could someone guide me to update the code?

Comment: Based on the `*INI` value need to change in main `*TEX` file

Comment: Just I want a guide on my struck... I don't want to ask anyone to write a code for me.

Comment: Does order of amacro, bmacro, cmacro lines can be changed or they will be fixed?? So we don't need to read whole file at once.

Comment: No. That is a whole content of main tex file I just entered the sample three lines which is matched the pattern where it is appeared in the `*ini` file.

Comment: Update you question with the number of lines in each file and some of the lines, which does not match at all.

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing but `my (@fpush,%stores) = "";` is equivalent to `my @fpush = ( "" ); my %stores;`.

Comment: You haven't explained the format of the INI file. What's the full syntax? Which parts are fixed and which are variable? How are you going to deal with nested brace groups in the TEX file?

Comment: If you're not asking us to write the code for you, then what exactly is your question? What kind of answer are you looking for?

Comment: @melpomene: I am modified the `*ini` file. I am also working in my script however not yet completed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume the `.ini` file contains regex/replacement pairs separated by tabs, one per line:

```
\\amacro\{(.*?)\}\{(.*?)\}  \amacro{$2}{$1}
\\bmacro\{(.*?)\}\{(.*?)\}\{(.*?)\}\{(.*?)\}    \bmacro{$4}{$3}{$2}{$1}
\\cmacro\{(.*?)\}\{(.*?)\}\{(.*?)\}\{(.*?)\}\{(.*?)\}\{(.*?)\}\{(.*?)\}\{(.*?)\}    \cmacro{$4}{$3}{$2}{$1}{$5}{$6}{$7}{$8}
```

This necessitates escaping the backslashes because otherwise e.g. `\a` would match the bell ("alert") control character, `\b` would match a word boundary, and `\cm` would match Ctrl-M (a.k.a. `\r`).

Then we can process it as follows:

```
# part A
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Open qw(fopen);
use Data::Munge qw(slurp replace);

# part B
my $text = slurp fopen 'test.tex';

# part C
my $fh = fopen 'tags.ini';
while (my $line = readline $fh) {
    chomp $line;
    my ($pattern, $replacement) = split /\t/, $line, 2;
    $text = replace $text, $pattern, $replacement, 'g';
}

print $text;
```

Part A enables `strict`/`warnings` and loads two helper modules ([File::Open](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Open), [Data::Munge](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Munge)) we're about to use.

Part B slurps the contents of `test.tex` into `$text` as one big string.

Part C loops over the lines of `tags.ini`. For each line it [removes the trailing newline](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) and splits it on the first tab into two fields, `$pattern` and `$replacement`. It then uses the [`replace` function from Data::Munge](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Munge#replace-STRING,-REGEX,-REPLACEMENT,-FLAG) to perform the actual search/replace operation. `replace` automatically handles capture groups and expands `$1`, `$2`, etc.

At the end it outputs `$text`, which is the contents of `test.tex` after all substitutions have been made.

---

If we wanted to, we could write the whole program as one expression (part C is effectively a [left fold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29) of a list):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Open qw(fopen);
use Data::Munge qw(slurp replace byval);
use List::Util qw(reduce);

print
    reduce
        { replace $a, split(/\t/, (byval { chomp } $b), 2), 'g' }
        slurp(fopen 'test.tex'),
        readline fopen 'tags.ini';
```

Comment: `$fh` we need to fopen for `*ini` file might be?

Comment: @ssr1012 Sorry, the declaration of `$fh` got lost in an edit. Fixed.

Comment: My sincere apologies for my mistake. Since I am copied the `*INI` where I have placed in my `OP question`. Hence the `tab delimit` has been changed to `white spaces`. I found the problem and now Its working fine champ... Awesome +1.

Comment: One question is there `my ($pattern, $replacement) = split /\t/, $line, 2;` why we are using `2` at the end of this line?

Comment: @ssr1012 See [`perldoc -f split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) for a description of `split` and what its arguments do.